# Simulate long key press (press and hold) using pynput

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.6, pynput

I'm using python3.6 and installed pynput through pip. I want a functionality to simulate a long key press (press and hold) of a key.

[image]

I tried commenting the release() function hoping that it will work as long press but only the key is pressed single time. Any solution to simulate long key press or any other alternative for pynput?

Comment: It should keep press and hold.

Comment: I have seen the same issue while monitoring (recording) through pynput . I guess this is a limitation of pynput .